# Stripes Framework file upload using apache fileupload

Tags: java, file-upload, stripes

I have been trying to integrate ck editor file upload with an  app developed using Stripes 1.8 but fail to succeed.
From CK editor file bowser (plain html) , I am able to hit a servlet which handles the file upload functionality. However the following section of code fail to execute.

```
// get uploaded file list
// the following code uses commons-fileupload-1.3.1
// the imports are removed for crispiness of the code
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
   try {
      List files = upload.parseRequest(request); // returns an empty list
   }catch (Exception e) { // no error handling}
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

What could be the reason and is there some kind of work around.
By the way, the same code is quite well working in Struts 1.3 application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the web.xml setup

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>stripesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When it is changed to

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>stripesFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The request has already been parsed since it goes through stripes servlet filter. Since the input stream has already been consumed by that earlier process, it is no longer available for parsing by Commons FileUpload.